# How to manage border spacing in tables?

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have the following `ajax` function which creates a table:

```
$(function() {
    var table = $('<table id="table2">');
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>').text(item.place.id),
    $('<td>').text(item.date), 
    );

     var $tr2 = $('<tr>').append(
     $('<td>').text(item.first),
      $('<td>').text(item.second));
      table.append($tr);
      table.append($tr2);

      $('#review').append(table);
 });
```

And my `CSS` looks like the following:

```
#table2 {
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing:1px 5px;
}
```

Here is what I get as the result:

[image]

I don't understand why the spacing between the rows are different. "First direct..", "First Canadian", "Secondig..","Third..." and "Fourth..." are actually the titles and what is mentioned under these titles belongs to them. So, I even prefer to have the "Kids friendly, green" closer to "First Direct..." than to "First canadian".

I tried with different numbers for`border-spacing` but it didn't help.

Comment: Try providing an [mcve] of the generated HTML. The JS is unlikely to be relevant (and since `data` is undefined it isn't very useful in its current state).

Comment: The border spacing is also really hard to see when *you haven't set a `border` on the cells*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest use 'reset CSS' every time you write something. Tell me if it helped, i'll try to recreate it if it wont help.